# OpenBSD: Move directories larger than X to new directory

Tags: find, cp, openbsd

I'm accessing OpenBSD via SSH and I'm wanting to create a command to find directories larger than 20MB and copy them to a new directory, keeping all folder structure.

So far I have this:

`find /source/directory/ -size +20000 -exec cp -iv --parents -t /destination/directory/`

But cannot get it to work!

Answer (score 1):

You are using OpenBSD's `cp` with options it doesn't have.

Take a look at the [manpage](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/cp.1).

> ```
> NAME
>      cp – copy files
>
> SYNOPSIS
>      cp [-fip] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] source target
>      cp [-fip] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] source ... directory
> ```

There is no `-iv` `--parents` and `-t`

**Update**

Also the `-exec` option is used wrong. It should be

> `-exec cp {} /destination/directory/ \;`

`cp` = the command
`{}` = what you want to copy. The results of `find`.
`/destination/directory/` = your destination
`\;` = the termination of the `-exec` option with a `;`  has to be escaped from the shell

Comment: Oh shoot...
So what about `find /source/directory/ -size +20000 -exec cp /destination/directory/` ?

I still can't get that to work.. It returns
`find: -exec: no terminating ";"`

and using
`find /source/directory/ -size +20000 cp /destination/directory/`
returns
`find: cp: unknown option`

Comment: Try `find /source/directory/ -size +20000 -exec cp {} /destination/directory/ \;`

Comment: `{}` for the file you wish to copy and `\;` because the `;``must be escaped (so the shell sees this as part of the command).

Comment: Awesome, thanks Thomas! It worked beautifully! You just saved me three days of labor hah

Comment: One more question - is 20000 20MB? When I do ls -l it lists things in bytes, so wouldn't 20000 be only 20KB?

Comment: According to the manpage size is counted in 512-byte blocks, so its 10 MB.

Comment: Oh that's right! So for 20MB I would need to say 39062.5, correct? Thanks again Thomas, I really appreciate it